Do we want to collect the best questions and answers at the end of each quarter?
This meta site contains several questions about the quality of questions and answers posted on the site. These seem to focus on what to do about low quality (unless I overlooked some).
We could also approach quality in a different way: collecting and showcasing the best questions and answers form the preceding quarter at the start of each new quarter. Literature Stack Exchange has been doing this for several years; see the best-of tag on its Meta site. (I know that someone said about my topic challenge suggestions that philosophy isn't literature, but I hope that the present suggestion translates better to this site.)
What does this require?

A volunteer who posts a new meta question to collect "nominations" from the quarter that has just ended.
From everyone else (well, this is just voluntary, of course): keeping track of good questions and answers. You can do this by saving them using the "Save this question" or the "Save this answer" button. You can manage these saves and keep them in a kind of folder named, e.g. "Best Q&A candidates". That way you don't need to wade through dozens (or more) contributions at the start of the new quarter.

Keep an eye out for questions and answers that are good but didn't get the number of upvotes they deserve.
Look out for great questions that have not been answered.
Keep track of great questions with great answers.


You submit the best questions and answer you have found in an answer to the meta post, ideally explaining what you find good about them.
If the site had a blog or a social media account, that could be used to promote the site by posting about high-quality content. But even without these "outlets", it is useful to highlight good content.
The cherry on the cake would be one or more high-rep users who reward some of the listed answers by low-rep users with a bounty. Obviously, this is entirely voluntary.

This approach does not prevent low-quality contributions but it provides an incentive for higher-quality content.
Let me know if you like this idea or even if you would like to take care of the quarterly meta posts. (I could do the meta posts myself if the idea is well-received.)

Good idea, but you withdrew your hat from the ring, no?

@JD The person posting the meta questions doesn't need to be a moderator. From that point of view, I don't see an impediment.

You're certainly right. :D Well, for five years, I've been interested in greater collaboration and communication in this site, and been hampered by a certain lack of others' interest. So, I place myself at your disposal if you're interested. Would you care to assign me a task?

Who decides "Best"?? If the answer is "democratically", then the vote system is already there for it — just order by score.  If OTOH some people's vote is to count more than others — and I dont think thats an unreasonable position to take, after all, all academic certification is exactly about this: "I have a PhD. So I am authorized to give PhDs" — then whats the certification?
The real difficulty is that on SE in general, eg. StackOverflow original and all the other tech/big sites, quality is at least possibly objective and the vote system tries to reify it, out here voting almost never happens on quality but almost always on agreement.

'Who decides "Best"??' People who care about quality. Based on the number of meta questions about quality, these people evidently exist. Voting on Literature SE is not entirely based on quality either, but those who respond to best-of questions never promote low-quality contributions. I think we should at least try it for a few quarters. If we notice it doesn't work, we can still abandon it. But what you never try can never work.

@Rushi I think for any non-main SE (stuff like Philosophy, RPG, SciFi, Travel, etc) past a certain point, the number of upvotes a question gets depends on how well it does in the "hot network questions" sidebar. E.g. it looks like this was the highest-voted question in the last literature.se quarter, but it wasn't nominated by the frequent users of meta.

I like the idea; I’ll post some stuff I’ve come across that I think is high-quality here for now.
Kant, Language, and Thought
Is Heideggerian “Being” like the instantiation of a class into an object?
